# Can Enum try parse method be a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I used a generic method to parse all these enum types, but there is an error, I am not sure how to fix it. Could someone have a great idea? Thanks

```
public static T TryParseEnum<T>(string value)
{
    T t;
    bool ok = Enum.TryParse<T>(value, out t);
    return t;
}
```

**Error**:

> The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'TEnum' in the generic type or method
>   'Enum.TryParse(string, out TEnum)'

**Update:**
Thanks yours help, and I have fixed it a new method.

```
public static T TryParseEnum<T>(string value) where T : struct
{
    T t = default(T);
    bool ok = Enum.TryParse<T>(value, out t);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: there is already a TryParse i guess in `Enum` type in BCL

Comment: FYI, in C# 7.3, there's a new `Enum` generic constraint: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2018/06/12/dissecting-new-generics-constraints-in-c-7-3/